# Symbolic Solution to Rational Equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following equation, which I would like to solve for `a` in terms of `x`, `y`, and `z`.  Additionally, I know that the denominator is nonzero.

$$\frac{505 (2 a+x+y-2 (a+x) (a+y)-z)^2}{2 (-1+a+x) (a+x) (-1+a+y) \
    (a+y)}==\frac{96}{25}$$

Clearly, I can multiply both sides by the denominator to get a quartic in `a`, which Mathematica can provide a symbolic solution for easily.  However, I have a bunch of equations like this and would like to get mathematica to solve them for me.  Running Solve on the above equation simply halts for several minutes.  I attempted to use `Simplify[..., a != x && a != y && a != 1 - x && a != 1 - y]` to get mathematica to convert the rational function into a polynomial, but it didn't work.  How can I get Mathematica to automatically solve such equations for me?

Comment: Please provide Mathematica code. The chance to get helpful answers will increase!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Running Solve on the above equation simply halts for several minutes

You did not show the command you used. You did not say which version of Mathematica you used. You also did not post the code in plain text.

> How can I get Mathematica to automatically solve such equations for
> me?

Use `Solve` ?

Using V 13.1 it solves it instantly for `a`. So I have no idea why it did not work for you. May be version of Mathematica difference?

```
ClearAll[a, x, y, z]
eq = (505*(2*a + x + y - 2*(a + x)*(a + y) - z)^2)/(2*(-1 + a + x)*(a + x)*(-1 + a + y)*(a + y)) == 96/25

sol = Solve[eq, a]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ah, I was doing `Solve[..., a, Reals]`, but I guess it was trying to find the conditions on x,y,z where those solutions are real, and that's why it was taking so long.